# Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, google-play-services, firebase-analytics

According to Google I/O 2016,I know the "Firebase",it is very nice for me,but I can not use it because this error.I have get a solution that update "Google play services" to 30,but no update tips.

[image]

Comment: That's strange. I just checked and *Update available: rev. 30* is visible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have to update your SDK Manager

[image]

Also you have to use

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

in your `buildscript` block and this version has to work with Google Play services 9.0 (+).

Comment: Thanks for anwser！

Comment: Had similar error for com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0, updating "Google Repository" and other to latest resolved the issue!

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0
```

instead of

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.0.0
```